# Identical values from different mountpoints

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Help me please!
I have virtual machine. Server Ubuntu 18.04 and install node-exporter prometheus under docker.
On server i have several disks.. But in metrics i see identical values from different disks. 
  Please help, what`s wrong? thanks!
[image: df info]

[image: metrics info]

[image: docker-compose file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Docker instructions in the node_exporter README](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#using-docker) you can see that you're missing the process settings. Add `pid: "host"`. You can also simplify the volume mounting.

```
node-exporter:
  pid: "host"
  volumes:
  - /:/host:ro,rslave
  command:
  - '--path.rootfs=/host'
```